# Inserting data into array with multiple same keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, soap, foreach

I'm using a SOAP API that uses an object array with multiple keys that are the same. This architecture can't be easily changed (suggested comma separated value but not possible, so open to other ideas here?)

I'm having difficulty feeding from a database a loop that puts multiple IDs into this array below. Because I don't believe it is possible for PHP to have an array that has keys with the same name.

This is the code below, which works fine when the CompanyID is hard coded in.

```
 $params = array(
        "APIUser"=>"",
        "APIPassword"=>"",
        "Companies"=>array(
                        "Company"=>array(
                            ["CompanyID"=>'101'], 
                            ["CompanyID"=>'121'], 
                            ["CompanyID"=>'323'],
                            ["CompanyID"=>'444'],
                            ["CompanyID"=>'551']
                        )
                    )
    );
```

But I need to get these IDs (how many there might be) and insert it into this array above.

How can I do this when the keys are the same? My efforts so far usually just rewrite a single CompanyID key with the last value in the loop.

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

**EDIT:** 
This is a SOAP request:

```
    <api:Companies>
          <api:Company>
               <api:CompanyID>101</api:CompanyID>

</api:Company>
          <api:Company>
               <api:CompanyID>121</api:CompanyID>            
        </api:Company>
                  <api:Company>
               <api:CompanyID>323</api:CompanyID>            
        </api:Company>
                  <api:Company>
               <api:CompanyID>444</api:CompanyID>            
        </api:Company>
                  <api:Company>
               <api:CompanyID>551</api:CompanyID>            
        </api:Company>
         </api:Companies>
```

Comment: The short answer is 'no', unfortunately. Refer to the link in my above comment.

Comment: When you say ___This architecture cannot be changed___ how much of that array structure is cast in concreat.

Comment: you have arrays in array, not array with same keys

Comment: That array must be changable as NO Language I know of allows duplicate array keys. The concept makes no sense

Comment: It's very hacky, but you could form the array with unique keys (i.e. `CompanyID1`, `CompanyID2`, etc.), convert the data to a string and modify it before you send it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - it could be changeable, I'm not used to SOAP and this is a 3rd party API, I requested a comma separated string for CompanyID but they aren't able to do this, is there another method they could maybe do that might work using arrays? Perhaps just equal to an array of values with no keys?

Comment: If you are using someoe elses API you have to conform to the parameter format they define. So how is this calls parameters defined?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for helping so far. I have added a SOAP request that the API requires to my post.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that your array will contain only company ids, why don't you do something like this?

```
$params = array(
        "APIUser"=>"",
        "APIPassword"=>"",
        "Companies"=>array(
            "Company"=>array('101', '121', '323', '444', 551') 
        )
    );
```

Comment: He can't do that because of the **first line** of his question: _I'm using a SOAP API that uses an object array with multiple keys that are the same. This architecture cannot be changed (and I know, it sucks)._